# Which target selector would return all players that have died 20 times?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to be able to detect a player that has died 20 times and then teleport that player only to an off-site area. I need to know how to detect that player but leave the others alone. I have tried to use /testfor commands but this is all I got so far.

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Deaths
/testfor @a [score_Deaths_min=20]
```

Could I possibly set a command to `/tp @a x,y,z =min_20`?

Comment: What have you tried already? Arqade works best when you show you've already made an effort in solving your problem. [Editing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/374574/edit) your post to include your past trials will show us that you've already tried a lot, and aren't giving up at the start. If you're stuck and don't know where to start, at least provide a list of ideas or roads you think *might* need to a solution.

Comment: The backticks and indentation by four spaces are there for a reason. We encourage the use of code font in Minecraft commands, and will edit anyone's post to include that.

Comment: The command in the last line (`/tp @a x,y,z =min_20`) doesn't have proper syntax. This makes it harder to find out what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you're getting the target selector right? Using scores is now different in the newest version of Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Instead of:

```
@a[score_DEATHS_min=20]
```

Try:

```
@a[scores={DEATHS=20..}]
```

And to solve your original problem, I directly targeted players to teleport in the `/tp` command.

```
/tp @a[scores={DEATHS=20..}] 10 20 30
```

**Explanation:** Teleport everyone with 20 deaths or more to coordinates (10, 20, 30).

Comment: Instead of `/execute @a[scores={DEATHS=20..}] ~ ~ ~ tp @s 10 20 30`, couldn’t you just use `/tp @a[scores={DEATHS=20..}] 10 20 30`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this solution out.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I am a new user and have no idea how to do that, nor can I find a green button on the page.